# Merger app.config from custom location

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have a scenario where I need to read an environment variable on start, then depending on the value of the ENV variable I need to merge a config file with the App.config file.

E.g.

```
MyApp.exe
MyApp.exe.config
Stage\MyApp.exe.config
Live\MyApp.exe.config
```

On start
-if the Environment variable = Stage, then Merge the config file in the Stage folder
-if the Environment variable = Live, then Merge the config file in the Live folder

If I had the following in the default MyApp.exe.config

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="SomeKey" value="SomeValue">
</appSettings>
```

and then had the following in the Stage\MyApp.exe.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SomeKey" value="Some NEW Value">
</appSettings>
```

I'd expect my application to read the value for SomeKey as "Some NEW Value".

I can't seem to find a clean way to implement this exact approach.

Thanks
Warrick

Comment: Why not just use different key values for the different environment variables?

Comment: Try to build to clients spec and they don't want to modify the source config files. So I ship my code with defaults and they place their overides in Stage\ or Live\ folder.

Comment: You don't need to modify source config files. Just choose which configuration values you use based on the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Build Events in Visual Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.90).aspx

You can use the variable to copy the overwrite the app.config in the pre-build event:

```
$(ConfigurationName)
```

If the config name is `DEV`, then copy the app.config.DEV over the app.config

If the config name is `PROD`, then copy the app.config.PROD over the app.config

Comment: While this is generally a good solution, I'm not 100% sure it would work in this situation. My understanding is this is when the app is already deployed and built.

Comment: There is a pre-build event and a post-build event you can tap into.  Just put it in the pre-build event.

Comment: Yup; but I think in this person's case the app is already deployed. Too late for build (pre or post) to be useful.

Comment: OK, I see.  I'm not sure if you can copy over the config file when the program first loads.  If not, I might pursue a .bat file solution or some scripting language that copies the right config file and then launches the EXE.